# How to Add checkbox in Jqgrid header

Tags: jqgrid

I do not mean the Multiselect column. In addition to that, Assume I have a column "Active" with checkboxes, I need a checkbox in its header, to select all/unselect all. Is this possible? Thanks.

I want to add a checkbox to the header of a column in jqgrid. This is my task.

Comment: Sorry, but your question is absolutely unclear. Do you wanted to post some comment to some another question? In general you should **post JavaScript code**, which you use or better post the demo (in JSFiddle) for example.

Comment: Sorry. <Column name="ACTIVE" index="ACTIVE" editable="true" sortable="true" editType="checkbox" search="true"  formatter="checkbox" width="140" key="false" displayOrder="8" title="ACTIVE">       
        <editOptions value="true:false"/>
      </Column> This is the column model for the column. I need a checkbox on its header. Hope you got my question now.

Comment: You should click on "edit" link below of the text of your question and **modify the text**. After the modification you should post comment with `@Oleg` to inform me about the changes. You can good format the code. HTML code have less sense to post. You should post **JavaScript code** which you use to create jqGrid (`colModel` with formatters, ...).

Comment: My code for creating jqgrid wouldnt help, its just the skeleton, all the data from id to colModel, gets loaded dynamically from xml. If I have to post my code, I have post the entire project. So if you understand my question, please tell me if its possible.

Comment: If you what that other helps you and answer on your questions you should answer on the answers of other people too. All what you wrote as free text can be interpreted in different ways. One have to guess what you really do. I wrote you in the comment to your previous question, that I suspect that the usage of custom column is not needed, but to be sure or to gives you some advises I need to know *what you do*.

Comment: The rules of stackoverflow: it's not forum where somebody debug your code. You should spend some time and formulate the question so that **it has some value for other people**. Thus you should not post your real long code. Instead of that you should create small readable demo, which reproduce the problem what you need to ask. For example simple local grid with two columns where one from the column is ACTIVE. You can load the data from simple XML file and include the small file.

Comment: I am sorry, I wish I could, reading grid settings from xml is not simple, I have separate project to do that. However, I will try to ask in such a way, in future. Thanks.

Comment: @It's do really simple, but I can't help you if I don't know the structure of XML file, I don't know which version of jqGrid and from which fork ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7) you use and I don't know from your current code which problem you have. You can create the demo in https://jsfiddle.net/ and use Echo service `/echo/xml/` (see [the documentation](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html)) to provide XML data dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

`colNames` or `label` of `colModel` items can contain **any HTML** code fragment. Thus you can place checkbox in the column header in the same way like you place the text in the header.

Comment: Thanks. I will try adding label property.

Comment: @RustinCohle: You are welcome! It's important that `label` property will be used **only if you don't use `colNames`** as jqGrid parameter. Thus it's always recommended that you post the code which you use.